# Using ipython notebook via SSH gives GLIBC not found error

Tags: ssh, jupyter-notebook, glibc, pyzmq, libsodium

I am trying to run ipython notebook via SSH in a virtualenv previously created on the computer directly logged in (no SSH). When doing so the ipython notebook fails with:

```
(venv2) [host]user: ipython notebook --nobrowser

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../venv2/bin/ipython", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(start_ipython())
  File ".../venv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 118, in start_ipython
    return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File ".../venv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 591, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-111>", line 2, in initialize
  File ".../venv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File ".../venv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 305, in initialize
    super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File ".../venv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File ".../venv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 386, in initialize
    self.parse_command_line(argv)
  File ".../venv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 300, in parse_command_line
    return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-4>", line 2, in parse_command_line
  File ".../venv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File ".../venv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 487, in parse_command_line
    return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)
  File "<decorator-gen-3>", line 2, in initialize_subcommand
  File ".../venv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File ".../venv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 418, in initialize_subcommand
    subapp = import_item(subapp)
  File ".../venv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipython_genutils/importstring.py", line 31, in import_item
    module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
  File ".../venv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 32, in <module>
    from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
  File ".../venv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    _libsodium = ctypes.CDLL(bundled_sodium[0], mode=ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
  OSError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by .../venv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/libsodium.so)
  linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc957cf000)
    libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007ffa27a84000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ffa27867000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007ffa274d2000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ffa272ce000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007ffa270cb000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007ffa26e46000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003f10400000)
  symbol memcpy, version GLIBC_2.14 not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference  (.../venv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/libsodium.so)
```

And ldd gives:

```
(venv2) [host]user: ldd -r -v .../venv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/libsodium.so
.../venv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/libsodium.so: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by .../venv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/libsodium.so)
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd835e7000)
    libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007f229227b000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f229205e000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2291cc9000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f2291ac5000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f22918c2000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f229163d000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003f10400000)
symbol memcpy, version GLIBC_2.14 not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference    (.../venv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/libsodium.so)

    Version information:
    .../venv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/libsodium.so:
        libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib64/libpthread.so.0
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.14) => not found
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.4) => /lib64/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib64/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib64/libc.so.6
    /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0:
        libdl.so.2 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib64/libdl.so.2
        libutil.so.1 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib64/libutil.so.1
        libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib64/libpthread.so.0
        libm.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib64/libm.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib64/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib64/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.4) => /lib64/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib64/libc.so.6
    /lib64/libpthread.so.0:
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.2) => /lib64/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib64/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib64/libc.so.6
    /lib64/libc.so.6:
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
    /lib64/libdl.so.2:
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib64/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib64/libc.so.6
    /lib64/libutil.so.1:
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib64/libc.so.6
    /lib64/libm.so.6:
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib64/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib64/libc.so.6
```

When using ipython notebook via normal desktop login it all works but using it via SSH always gives this error. Reinstalling the venv via SSH did not help. I do not have root access neither do I have sudo.

Any ideas how to get it to work?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

From https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html:

```
The venv module provides support for creating lightweight “virtual environments”
with their own site directories, optionally isolated from system
site directories.
```

Apparently your virtual environment is isolated from the system, *and also* is using older version of GLIBC. The SSH part of your question is likely a red herring, it's the `venv` that causes your problems, not ssh.

You can find the version of glibc inside and outside of venv by running `/lib64/libc.so.6`.

Once you confirm that the `libc.so.6` inside `venv` is older than 2.14 ... there is very little you can do to fix this.

You can work with whoever maintains your `venv` to get GLIBC inside of it updated to match system one, or you can try to create binaries that don't require `GLIBC-2.14`.

The latter solution is non-trivial. Two common approaches are to compile/link your binaries inside a `chroot` environment, or using a linux-to-older-linux cross-compiler.

A more viable approach might be to always build your binaries *inside* the `venv`. They will then work both inside and outside of it.